# IE11 doesnt Follow Link Even After onclick=“return true;”

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with link not following even after onclick returns true. it works fine in chrome and firefox. I have noticed this particular behaviour only of the anchor is in  tag.I am using bootstrap for the responsiveness(not sure if this is impacting..)

Sample:

```
<form>
<a id="SignonButton" class="SignonButton" HREF="https://www.google.com" onClick="return true;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" name="button1">Inside form doesnt work</button>
        </a>
</form>

<a id="SignonButton" class="SignonButton" HREF="https://www.google.com" onClick="return true;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" name="button1">Outside form works</button>
        </a>
```

@TJ Yes indeed it worked. 
Actually i am revamping one existing form to make it responsive the form has two actions and two input elements
1. HREF="Javascript:transferRequest()" 
2. onClick="validateRequest()"

form has two input elements input1:email and input2: password.

what i can understand from the existing code is that validateeRequest() validates the email pattern(x@y.z) and alphanum pattern for password and returns true

if both the patterns match.

validate request checks two text boxes to confirm if the input text matches pattern or not(does not validate just check if pattern matches or not, transfer

request actually transfers the two texts as it is to server).

As suggested using `<a>` for the button is correct or I need to add the validation methods to button
I am not allowed to completely revamp the site, just convert it to responsive.

```
<div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="TEXT" size="16" maxlength="19" autocomplete="OFF">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="Password" >Password</label>
    <input type="PASSWORD" size="16" maxlength="19" autocomplete="OFF>
</div>
<div>   
    <a id="SignonButton" HREF="javascript:transferRequest('verify')" onClick="return ValidateRequest('Verify');">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" name="button1">Inside form doesnt work</button>
        </a>
</div>
</form>


function transferRequest()
{

var form = document.loginForm;
document.loginForm.submit();//submits to local exchange server
//some crazy validation 
}

function validateRequest()
{
// code to check if the email input follows pattern (x@y.z) or not
// code to check if the password has alphanum as pattern or not
//return true if both pattern matches
}
```

Comment: Probably due to an interactive element (`<button>`) inside of an anchor (`<a>`). Do you intercept the click in a button handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a `button` inside a link. It's [invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), `a`'s content model is

> Transparent, but there must be no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.

Because it's invalid, a browser is free to do whatever it thinks it should do, including relocating the button outside the link.

Separately, `return true` has no effect whatsoever in an `onClick`. (`return false` does, but not `return true`.)

So what you need to do is modify your content to make it valid. Then it may work correctly cross-browser. Since you're using Bootstrap, two choices there:

1. Get rid of the `button` entirely:

   ```
   <a id="SignonButton" class="btn btn-primary SignonButton" href="https://www.google.com">Click Me</a>
   ```

   That looks like a button because of the Bootstrap styles.
2. Get rid of the link entirely:

   ```
   <button type="button" id="SignonButton" class="SignonButton btn btn-primary" onclick="location = 'http://www.google.com'>Click Me</button>
   ```

#1 would be strongly preferred, since it is a link after all.

Answer (score 0):

Take the buttons out of the  tag. It's not valid as already mentioned. Use something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" name="button1" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';">Inside form should work. ;)</button>
```